# Should we always use `override` in Trait

Tags: scala, diamond-problem

Should we always use `override` in Trait to solve preemptively the diamond inheritance issue ?

Let's see an example to explain the point :

```
trait S { def get : String }
trait A extends S { override def get = "A" }
trait B extends S { override def get = "B" }
class C extends A with B
```

Without `override`, the following doesn't compile.

Comment: What would you expect `new C().get` to return?

Comment: That sounds like a easy way to produce unexpected results if similar traits are overriding each other. I think the better question is, in what case would you ever *want* `C` with `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `override` will make it compile, but the real question is: what are you trying to achieve?

In scala, traits you're extending from are linearized. This means that

```
class C extends A with B
new C().get
```

will produce `"B"`

but

```
class C extends B with A
new C().get
```

will produce `"A"` instead.

So what do you expect? Generally speaking, depending on the order of the inheritance for solving the diamond problem seems like a terrible design choice (while there are legitimate uses of this language feature, like the stackable trait pattern)

So, back to the original question, should you always use override? No, you simply should avoid diamonds in your inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: There's still stackable trait pattern that can benefit from the order (http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html) but may be not a 'terrible design choice'

Comment: @abatyuk right, wrong wording. I meant for solving the diamond problem, while of course there are legitimate uses of that feature. Updated my answer